# Stability of a linear equation

Tags: operator-theory, stability-theory

If $A$  is a matrix, then $e^{At} \leq C e^{-\lambda t}$ if and only if the spectrum of $A$ consists of eigenvalues with negative real parts.

Is there a similar result, relating stability to the spectrum, when $A$ is a non-selfadjoint operator, when $e^{-At}$ is interpreted as the solution to
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = - A u,$$
with appropriate boundary conditions? I assume that there is, but I haven't been able to find a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some assumptions on $A$ to have a unique solution of the evolution equation (and one should also talk about the type of solution). Anyway, I think the answer to your question lies in the [Hille-Yosida theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hille%E2%80%93Yosida_theorem):

If $A$ is the generator of the strongly continuous semigroup $T$, then $\|T(t)\|\leq M e^{\omega t}$ if and only if the spectrum of $A$ is contained in the half-plane $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid \operatorname{Re}z\leq \omega\}$.

In this case $u(t)=T(t)x$ is the unique mild solution of the initial value problem
\begin{align*}
\dot u(t)&=Au(t),\\
u(0)&=x.
\end{align*}
The Hille-Yosida theorem also gives a characterization of the operator that generate strongly continuous semigroups.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't there another assumption in the Hille-Yosida theorem though, namely that $\|(\lambda I - A)^{-n} \| \leq \frac{M}{(\lambda - \omega)^n}$ for every real $\lambda > \omega$?